# hive reach max worker and cannot connect to hiveserver2

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

when i use beeline connect to hiveserver2 ,the err msg is like this.
I have connect to the hiveserver2 before.
This error is show after i connect to hiveserver2 some times.
and i can connect use jdbc:hive2://

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://master:10000
```

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://master:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://master:10000: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://master:10000: 
17/11/14 22:09:36 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to master:10000
Unexpected end of file when reading from HS2 server. The root cause might be **too many concurrent connections**. Please ask the administrator to check the number of active connections, and adjust hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads if applicable.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://master:10000: null (state=08S01,code=0)

hive-site.xml is set like this

```
<property>
 39         <name>hive.server2.thrift.min.worker.threads</name>
 40         <value>5</value>
 41     </property>
 42     <property>
 43         <name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
 44         <value>500</value>
 45     </property>
 46     <property>
 47         <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
 48         <value>master</value>
 49     </property>
 50     <property>
 51         <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
 52         <value>10000</value>
 53     </property>
```

i have check the netstat that 10000 port is listening.
even if i restart the hadoop server and hiveserver2,the problem is not solved. 
how can i know how many connection is active or can i clear the thread pool?
The active will not be closed when i shutdown the hiveserver and hadoop and linux system?

Comment: anyone help me? i have tried two days

Comment: Same problem here. anyone plz

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my environment:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 10000
tcp4       0      0  *.10000                *.*                    LISTEN
```

- hive-site.xml

set nosasl for not using SASLTransport

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>NOSASL</value> <!-- default NONE is for SASLTranspor
</property>

 <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>false</value> <!-- Execute query as hiveserver2 proc
</property>
```

and

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;auth=noSasl hive password org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

- REFERENCES

This is Japanese blog but it would be helpful: http://tagomoris.hatenablog.com/entry/20131226/1388044783

Comment: @Oukafu, can you please share the steps you performed, we are facing the same issue from the past couple of days and looking for the resolution.